# How to send record(which is a weblink) from a table to the value of the variable in SSIS package and send that weblink through an email?

Tags: sql, ssis

I have table called Table1 with columns, col1 and col2 with col1 having weblinks for the report and col2 the name of the report. Now, i have a package with a variables var1 and var2 which should get the col1 and col2 values respectively from table1 and send it through an email. if the weblink gets updated in the table, package should send the updated link. i know the reverse way of it but trying to do somethig like this.

Appreciate any help from you guys.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this.  You can try one of the following based on whether you are processing one row or many rows.

**One-Row Solution**
If you are running the SSIS package so that it will process one and only one row from the table, you can use the Execute SQL Task to get the values from your table.  Begin by adding your two variables

In the task, specify the connection to your SQL Server and enter a SQL statement like this.

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM Table1
WHERE <your condition to retrieve one row>
```

Also, on the General tab, set the ResultSet value to Single row.

On the Result Set tab, add two elements. The first row should be Result Name of 0, Variable Name of Var1.  The second row will be Result Name 1, Variable Name Var2.

When the task runs, the results of the SQL statement will be stored to the variables.

**Multi-Row Solution**
If the SSIS package must return multiple rows, then you need a different approach.  First, you will need to create another variable that is an Object data type.  The SQL results will be saved to this variable.

You will have an Execute SQL Task that is similar to the one above.  However, your SQL statement should return all rows to be processed.  The ResultSet property should be set to Full result set.  On the Result Set tab, there should be one result set, with 0 as Result Name and your new object variable as the Variable Name.  Close the Execute SQL Task editor.

Add a Foreach Loop Container.  Edit the container and select the Collection tab.  Set the Enumerator property to Foreach ADO Enumerator.  Under the Enumerator configuration, set your object variable as the ADO object source variable.

On the Variable Mappings tab, add to rows.  The first row will have a Variable Var1 and Index 0, and the second row will have Variable Var2 and Index 1.  The Foreach Loop Container will process each for in the result set and assign the column values to your variable.  You can add any tasks in the container and they will run once for each row in the result set.

Comment: Thank you very much. thats how an answer should be. thanks. just one question how do i see the value of the variable, i dont see it in variables window?

Comment: You can view the variable values at runtime by setting breakpoints.  For example, if you want to see the values at every iteration of the Foreach Loop Container, you can set a breakpoint on the container.  Right-click the container and select Edit Breakpoints.  Check the Enabled boxes for the appropriate events, "Break at the beginning of every iteration of the loop" in this case.  Start the package and when there's a break, look in the Locals window for your variables to see the current values.  Click the start button to continue processing.

Comment: Thanks bob. really appreciate your help and your expertise in SQL. Thanks a million.